# How to configure two infrared light to produce two different intensity

Tags: electricity, infrared-radiation, light-emitting-diodes

I have two infrared illuminators that have the same properties (same wavelength, same number of leds, same angles, same max voltage and amperage). suppose that these illuminators are attached at the same height and they are equidistant to an object in the scene and we suppose that the scene is uniform (constant reflexion). How can I do to make these illuminator generate different shadows (one is more dark ). I am wondering that I should use different amperage or different voltage. Any comment please.

Comment: What is about an semitransparent foil in front of one of the spots?

Comment: How many LEDs? And do you have access to the wiring for each?  To get different output intensities from LEDs I usually use transistors to power them.  Whether this is a feasible option or not will depend on what your system is.

Comment: @tmwilson26 there are 140 LEDs. it is like this model http://www.amazon.ca/Infrared-illuminator-Vision-adapter-outdoor/dp/B00C0P0DRS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1445167764&sr=8-1&keywords=illuminator+infrared

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering that I should use different amperage or different voltage.

If all you have is a bunch of LEDs with their leads exposed, or with a very basic current limiting device (a resistor, usually), then this could work.

If you have an assembly of LEDs with a power supply of some kind, then likely it won't work. The power supply will try to compensate for any reduction in input voltage/current, and ultimately could be damaged if you operate it outside it's specified operating conditions.

> How can I do to make these illuminator generate different shadows

There are several options:

- Place an attenuating filter (such as a neutral density filter) in front of one of the sources.
- Place a screen partially in front of one of the sources (depending on the configuration of your system and the shape of the screen, this could change the shadow produced by more than just the intensity)
- If you have access, simply remove some of the LEDs from one of the sources. Whether and how well this works will depend on whether the LEDs are wired in series or parallel, what kind of power source is driving the LEDs, etc.)
- Paint an opaque paint over some of the LEDs in one of the sources.
- ...

Comment: I think it will work. In fact, since two or three month, I had 4 illuminators where all having 140 LEDs but one of them having different amperage (i forgot if it higher or less than). I have used the power supply of the different one and I remark that this illuminator had a higher intensity then other.